# Android Emulator Not Shown In Debug Menu On First Start In Visual Studio 2019

Tags: android, xamarin.forms, android-emulator, visual-studio-2019

I have a weird problem going on with Android Emulators in Visual Studio 2019. Whenever I launch a new instance of VS2019 my emulator devices do not show up in the debug menu. The debug toolbar comes up with an empty list:

[image]

Although I have devices installed:

[image]

But when I go into SDK Manager and change something like installing or removing a new/existing SDK or tool, even the unrelated ones, the emulators suddenly start appearing in the list again:

[image]

And I can debug with no problems. But after this step if I close and re-launch Visual Studio or start a new instance without closing, everything goes back to step 1.

I've tried every solution I could find online and nothing seems to do the trick.

- My Visual Studio version : Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2019 Version 16.11.7
- I'm running VS as admin
- Android Emulator version : 31.1.4
- I also have Android Studio Installed ( I don't know if it has anything to do with this issue.)
- OS : Windows 10 Pro 19043.1348

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Edit (12/17/2021 18:44 UTC):

I forgot to mention; Restart Adb Server option in VS > Tools > Android is always greyed out. Maybe somehow it is related to this issue.

**UPDATE**(12/19/2021 06:55 UTC)

---

@ToolmakerSteve:
Here's my Android SDK location:

[image]

I also tried to change it to point to another folder and re-downloading all SDKs into the new folder. Unfortunately no change.

And I don't have anything related to `ANDROID_HOME` in `Environment Variables`.
And I don't have `C:\Users\Emre\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk`
folder in my system.

I also tried to uninstall VS and remove everything in the Android SDK folder and reinstall. But no change.

Comment: Do you have any update on this? I am suddenly facing the same problem

Comment: @Digital_Jo4 No I couldn't find a way to fix the issue in VS2019. I've upgraded to VS2022 and looks like everything is working fine so far.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to display the Android virtual machine you created in the Android Emulators menu, generally speaking, it can be recognized. If not recognized, you need to open the Android Device Manager first.

Select the device you want to run and click the Start button, so that the virtual machine can be started and detected, and then your virtual machine The device will be added to the Android Emulators menu.

Comment: Unfortunately starting the device from the device manager did not solve the problem. Even while the device is running Visual Studio does not detect it and I cannot debug.

Answer (score 0):

This usually means a different version of "adb.exe" (the bridge between VS and emulator) is already running.

Things to try:

1. Sign out (or reboot pc), then sign in again. Run VS, open your project, wait several minutes. Does it find the devices? Hopefully once it has done it once, it will do better next time.
2. Task manager, show more details, find any `adb.exe`, End Task. If there are more than one, kill them all.
3. I don't think Android Studio interferes, unless you run it. If you do, you'll need to do either (1) or (2), so VS can use its own `adb.exe`.
4. Maybe check Task Manager / Startup - disable anything there that mentions Android or adb? Then reboot.
5. Wen xu Li's answer (start device via Android Device Manager) should always get you past this - though it won't permanently fix the situation.

**UPDATE**

---

(6) Check VS / Options menu / Xamarin / Android Settings / Android SDK Location - is it

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk
```

Check System's `Environment Variables`. (On Windows 10: Edit the system environment variables / Advanced tab / Environment Variables button.)
There is probably `ANDROID_HOME` from Android Studio. On mine, it has value

```
C:\Users\???\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk
```

Find that folder. As a test, rename it. I forgot had previously renamed my "Android" as "Android-old", so that the environment variable would no longer find that sdk.

If that works, then consider deleting `ANDROID_HOME` environment variable, or changing it to point to the location that is found in VS / .. / Android SDK Location.

Comment: 1. I've rebooted and run VS, waited for 2-3 minutes; no change. 
2. After restart there's no adb.exe entry in task manager. But If I run a new instance of VS, go into Android Device Manager and start the virtual device an adb.exe (32 bit) entry is added. Killing it does not solve the problem.
4. Nothing related to android or adb in Startup.
5. Starting device via ADV also doesn't change anything.
Then only solution I've come up with is SDK Manager > Tools >Extras > Install or Remove anything. Then I can debug. But I have to do this step for every instance of VS running.

Comment: @Emre - hmm. This is very strange. The adb.exe started by SDK Manager should be the same one started by ADM. It should also start when VS opens your Android project. check Options / Xamarin / Android Settings / Android SDK Location - is it `C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk`?

Comment: See my Update (6). Forgot I previously had an issue with a second Android SDK location (which also includes adb.exe). Android Studio installation probably. Make it so that other one is not found via `ANDROID_HOME` environment variable.

Comment: See my update to the original post please. Unfortunately no change to the issue.

Comment: I guess Android Studio changed how they install the sdk. Find out where they put it.

Answer (score 0):

Within Android Manifest, I had to lower the API versions from API Level 33 to API Level 30:

[image]

Then the emulators displayed in Visual Studio.

Answer (score 0):

I updated my visual studio 2022 and Visual studio now shows all android devices.